# Oracle-How to find partition information depending on the data in table ? ORA 14400

Tags: sql, oracle, database-partitioning

Trying to copy data from one environment to other.

Created partitions and sub partitions as per the source table but still getting error : Inserted partition key does not map to any partition.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some steps to try:

1. Double and triple check the partition and subpartition definitions and boundaries. They are easy to mess up, especially with subpartitioning. You have to actually check the subpartitioning layout in *all* the partitions. Just because a subpartition exists in one partition doesn't mean it has to exist in another. The partition names are irrelavent.. what matter is the boundaries (`HIGH_VALUE` in `DBA_TAB_PARTITIONS/SUBPARTITIONS`, which is unfortunately a `LONG` and therefore requires a PL/SQL workaround to query programmatically).
2. Check your insert statement and verify that you are putting the right source columns in the right target columns. Use explicit column lists both the `INSERT` and `SELECT` clauses, don't rely on default column order. It may be sticking the wrong column in your partitioning key.
3. If all the above checks out, find out if partition exchanges ever happen on the source table. It is possible for the source table owner to have done partition exchanges with the "`WITHOUT VALIDATION`" clause in order to speed things up. This can result in the wrong data being in the wrong partition, which won't throw an error until you try to select this data out and insert it into another similar partitioned table, at which point it is doing the validation and can throw the error if it doesn't map to some other partition.
4. Remember that subpartitions can vary from partition to partition. You may have taken the definition from the latest one, or the first one, or the subpartition template, none of which guarantees that's what you need for *all* the partitions. One easy to test if this is the problem is to make sure there is a `(DEFAULT)` subpartition defined (assuming it's `LIST`) to catch any outliers.
5. If it's a `RANGE` partition (e.g. some date column) you can create a distant future date partition (e.g. `VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('12/31/9999','MM/DD/YYYY'))`  ), then attempt the insert. If there's rogue future date it will go into that future partition and you can then query it to find out what date it was.
6. Lastly, consider not defining your partitions at all, but using `INTERVAL` (if `RANGE`) or automatic list (if `LIST`) so that Oracle automatically creates the partitions as you insert data (e.g. `PARTITION BY RANGE(datecol) INTERVAL NUMTOYMINTERVAL(1,'MONTH')`. You'll still have to define a subpartition template so your subpartitions gets created with each one. I find interval partitioning to be desirable any time it's possible (with a few outlying exceptions). It's your friend and saves a lot of typing and error-prone partition definitions.

Comment: Thanks , point 4 helped to resolve the issue. A part of the subpartion's values was missing  in the target table .But one thing to note : there was a default partition with Null subpartition values , the data in question should have got loaded there but it didn't :(

Answer (score 1):

looks like the  partition on which you are trying to insert data is not present, you have 2 options.

1. Get the DDL from the source table and create those partitions on the target.
2. Run this query ,
   select partition_name,column_name,high_value,partition_position
   from ALL_TAB_PARTITIONS a , ALL_PART_KEY_COLUMNS b
   where table_name='YOUR_TABLE' and a.table_name = b.name;

This query lists the column name used as key and the allowed values. make sure, you insert the allowed values(high_value). Else, if default partition is defined, it would go there.

thanks